# Update Based on a common value where there are multiple matches

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've got two tables (MySQL database), one called cities (that has columns 'state_id' and 'stateAB'--state_id is the row I would like to fill, stateAB is the 2-letter code of the state--I want this to serve as the key value).

I have another table called states (that has columns 'id' [this is the value that I want to go into the 'state_id' field of 'cities'], and a 'title' field [2-letter state codes] to be the common-key value).

I wanted to use a simple:

```
UPDATE cities SET state_id=(SELECT id FROM states WHERE states.title=cities.stateAB)
```

With the idea being that state_id will be set to the id that is returned where the 2-letter codes match.

The problem is that the following is returned:

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I assume this is because there are more than one time per state that the codes match, for the simple reason that there are multiple cities per state (and they all have the same state/codes).

I'm not sure how to change this to make it work--I'm sure it's something obvious I'm just missing, but I don't know how to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE cities
    SET state_id = (SELECT id FROM states WHERE states.title = cities.stateAB);
```

You are getting the error because `states` has duplicates in the `title` column.  You can find these by running:

```
select title, count(*) as numdups
from states
group by title
having count(*) > 1;
```

You may not care about the duplicates, happy to select just one id (consistently) when there is a match.  If so, you can do:

```
UPDATE cities
    SET state_id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM states WHERE states.title = cities.stateAB);
```